# how to get libtorrent to see boost?

Tags: c++, boost, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am compiling libtorrent-rasterbar-0.16.16 with msys and mingw.
./configure runs fine, until it gets to the boost library check.
I have boost 1.51, and I set $BOOST_ROOT, but that did not work.

```
Checking for boost libraries:
checking for boostlib >= 1.36... expr: syntax error
configure: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.36 or higher). If
you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT
 in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are
sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/
version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... no
configure: error: Boost.System library not found. Try using --with-boost-system=
lib
```

I tried the --with-boost-system= option, and that did not work either.  I also copied libboost_system-mgw47-mt-1_51.a to the same directory as libtorrent... but it did not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: you say you tried the --with-boost arguments. what exactly did you pass in?

Comment: ./config --with-boost-system=./libboost_system-mgw47-mt-1_51.a

Answer (score 1):

> I have boost 1.51, and I set $BOOST_ROOT, but that did not work

It is very likely that configure can’t find boost header files. **What you need is both the library and the sources**, and your best avenue is still setting BOOST_ROOT.

On a linux box you would be installing the `boost-devel` package, but for mingw you should download the boost sources directly and unpack them. Then please make sure you are running,

```
BOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost_1_51 ./configure
```